# Rails has_one left_outer_join association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am struggling to work with a has_one association.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office
end
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee    # foreign key - employee_id
end
```

I would like to return a list of employees who have no office. I would have expected to use the following however this does not work.

```
Employee.left_outer_joins(:office).where("office.id = null")
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Apologies. It just returns an empty AR relation

Comment: Do you any records that meets the condition?

Comment: Also try changing it to `Employee.left_outer_join(:office).where("office.id IS null")`

Comment: Employee.count = 22 & Employee.joins(:office).count = 1

Comment: IS null worked. Please post answer and I will accept. Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak your query to the below

```
Employee.left_outer_joins(:office).where("office.id IS null")
```

This also works

```
Employee.left_outer_joins(:office).where(office: {id: nil})
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my original question, please update your answer from left_outer_join to left_outer_joins